# Is it possible to override "Roboto" Font by any other webfont?

Tags: google-mirror-api

According to base style https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/assets/css/base_style.css the "**Roboto**" is the default Glass font.

Is it possible to use some other webfont (override the Roboto)?

I am sure that ingress player would like to change "**Roboto**" for "**coda_regular**"

Answer (score 9):

Importing font is not supported by the Mirror API and the only font available in the client is indeed Roboto.