# Is use of Inline-CSS like (style="color:ffaa00;font-family:times;") allowed in Google Glass Mirror API?

Tags: css, colors, webfonts, google-mirror-api

Is it allowed (in google mirror api) when writing HTML,
to use any CSS with code like:

```
<h1 style="color:#ffaa00;font-family:times;">
```

to enable custom color or webfonts ?

In the **playground it works**, but I´m not sure, if it will be actually working on google glass.

Or is just the pre-set
 ["base-style.css"](https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/assets/css/base_style.css)
allowed.

Copy the code below.
[Go to playground!](https://developers.google.com/glass/playground) 
Use *"Chrome-Browser"*  and switch input from "*JSON to HTML*"

to check out this working example.

```
    <article>
      <section>
        <p class="text-auto-size">This <em class="yellow">paragraph</em> 
is base-style-css.<br> 
    This    <strong style="color:#ffaa00;font-family:times;">HTML</strong> 
is custom style css.<br>
    enabled with <_strong style="color:#ffaa00;">
        </p>
      </section>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web fonts are not supported on Glass at this time. In fact, no other fonts but Roboto are allowed at this time.

You should be able to specify whatever color you want using standard CSS methods for color and standard HTML methods for indicating class or style, although the suggested colors are in place to keep the cards looking (and working) fairly consistently.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a list of allowed CSS for glass, or is just font-family restricted and nothing else?

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively, and I'm sure there is lots of CSS markup that won't work, but most other formatting should work about as you expect. I'll repeat, however, that you probably don't want to get too too fancy because it will look dramatically different than other cards.

Answer (score 1):

`style="color:#ff0000;"` is standard inline-styling and I can't imagine Google would block the ability to styles HTML elements in such basic way.

I'm not sure how new you are to HTML/CSS, but my guess is that you're getting confused by the example's use of `class="yellow"` which affectively does the same thing as `style="color: #db1;"`

In case of the example, they've created a CSS class called 'yellow' which looks like this:

```
.yellow {
    color: #db1;
}
```

In short, with the above CSS rule included, these two would output the same:

```
<p class="yellow">I'm yellow text</p>
<p style="color: #db1;">I'm yellow text, too</p>
```

If your question is about which *color names* are usable in HTML, without the hex-values, here's a link to that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors. Mind you, some browsers understand a broader spectrum, but that links lists the widely-accepted bunch.

TLDR; If it works in Google's playground, it will more-thank-likely work in the actual implementation, **especially** if it's standard HTML/CSS styling.

Comment: Because of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045900/is-it-possible-to-override-roboto-font-by-any-other-webfont I was concerned if the font change was possible, and because of these 7 proposed colors in the base-style.css i wasn´t sure if google is aiming to keep colors limited for usability and clear design. I am not confused about class="yellow", but thanks for the word "inline css" and your advise

Comment: Hmm, well it seemed 99% of your question, including the title, was about `color`, not `webfonts`, just saying. Ironically enough, your username is also `AddingColor`.

Comment: I mean, I reckon that base style sheet just provides a shortcut to some color names—you could always extend it—I assume. If not by an external stylesheet, possibly by a <style> block. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just changed question to webfonts too, sry bout not asking clearly

Comment: Now I do understand that Google is just enabling shortcuts, and not restricting the design.

Comment: sorry I didn´t accepted your answer, just because it was about color and not fonts as well (due to my non-edited question), and I can´t vote up your answer cause I don´t have enough reputation yet.Thank you really much for your detailed answer about colors and inline-style !